# how to disable text in input type number when you enable speech

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, input

How can I prevent text from appearing in the number input field when speech recognition is enabled?
It's not working even though I used `@media speech` and disabled it in JS.

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <label for="quantity">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
@media speech {
[type="number"] {
    speak: digits;
    speak-as: spell-out;
  }
}
[type="number"]{
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.querySelector('#quantity').webkitSpeech = false;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use `document.querySelector('#quantity').disabled = true;` to disable input field when using speech recognition

Comment: You are right but I want user can add input from keyboard as well as from speech but by disabling input user can not input from keyboard. This number field will only allow user to add numbers but with speech user is able to input alphabets  as well